# How to expand Hexadecimal 0x38 as 00 00 00 38 using python?

Tags: python, hex, decimal

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgTIe.jpg)

I'm referring to an index location in a log file which has a decimal value that I need to convert into hexadecimal using

--> `a = hex(int(line[100:103])- 24)` to output for eg:"0x38"

Is there a way to output it as 00 00 00 38 instead of 0x38?

I have to compare the output against the output I get from the next line (which would look properly like 00 00 00 38) and check if they both are the same.

Or, I'd be extracting info my next line in the log file through this

--> `b = line[148:159]`

which would output for eg: 00 00 00 38. If I can't do the former, would I be able to shrink this as 0x38?

Sorry I'm new to this, hope I made it clear. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 24? Is that just because you know there's a difference of 24dec between the two values?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: @Grismar That's right.

Answer (score 2):

A "bytes" object have an`hex` method which has an optional separator argument. So, just convert your 0x38 to a 4 byte long bytes (big endian), and call hex:

```
In [18]: 0x38 .to_bytes(4, "big").hex(" ")
Out[18]: '00 00 00 38'
```

(note the whitespace between the literal `0x38` and the `.to_bytes` :  that is a necessary syntactic trick to be able to call methods on numeric literals. If the value is in a variable, as usual, the space obviously is not needed)

Comment: What version of Python are you using that needs the space?

Comment: Oh, actually, I did not notice that for hexadecimal literals the space is not needed.
It is with plain decimal integers, though, so that calling methods is dinguished from a literal float.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get it as a hexadecimal with padding? In that case, you could use

```
a = hex(int(line[100:103])- 24)[2:].zfill(8)
a = ' '.join([a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)])
```

Which turns "0x38" into "00 00 00 38" as a string

**Edit:**
To do the reverse of what you asked you could do this

```
b = ''.join(line[148:159].split())
b = hex(int(b, 16))
```

Which turns "00 00 00 38" into the prefered "0x38" (which may end up being a lot easier for you to use to add and subtract over the former since you can convert to an integer and just do normal math on it with `int(b[2:], 16)` and then back again by using `hex()` as normal

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried with the code you suggested but it returns -> 'TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation' for this line: 

a = ' '.join([a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)])

Comment: That probably means that you copied and pasted it while having a different spacing from what Stack Overflow offers. In Python, all the white space behind a line must be equal to the line before it. Except when you have a new function, where the white space must be larger than the previous line, so it's more indented. You return to the old white space size when your function ends. In your case, it could be just easiest to delete all the white space before both lines to make sure that they're equal, as long as everything above them is equal to that. Otherwise, you should use that size instead